How add different colors to gvisOrgCharts nodes?
I want to add multiple colors to the nodes of a gvisOrgChart.  Ideally I would like to use a column from the source dataframe to indicate the color. Here I have used the packages standard example using the Regions dataset and added a color column to it.
library(googleVis)

Regions

cols <- c("red", rep("green",3), rep("blue",7))

Regions$col <- cols

Org <- gvisOrgChart(Regions, 
                    options=list(width=600, height=250,
                                 size='large', allowCollapse=TRUE))
plot(Org)


The package's introduction suggests that colors could be added via options like this: options=list(colors="['#cbb69d', '#603913', '#c69c6e']").  When I tried that with a list of colors for each node in the data, it did not work. I could get it to work with one color, but then that color was applied to every node.
On the Google Charts site I found reference that color is deprecated. It says to use nodeClass instead for the background color of the orgchart elements. Under nodeClass it says, "A class name to assign to node elements. Apply CSS to this class name to specify colors or styles for the chart elements."
I don't know how the syntax works to integrate nodeClass into the above code. Ideally I would like to be able to reference the Regions$col field for the colors.
